# How to group Associations' attributes in a Collection (Active Model Serializer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

Consider the below two entities: Posts, Authors

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, author_id
  belongs_to :author
end

Class AuthorSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
end
```

Using the 'JSON' adapter, for the index action of PostsController we get the response as below:

```
{
  "posts":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "title":"Hic consectetur et delectus",
      "author_id": 1,
      "author":{"id":1,"name":"Author-A"}
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "title":"Hic consectetur et delectus",
      "author_id": 2,
      "author":{"id":2,"name":"Author-B"}
    },
    {
      "id":3,
      "title":"Hic consectetur et delectus",
      "author_id": 1,
      "author":{"id":1,"name":"Author-A"}
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to group the Authors data outside the Posts data for sideloading? (as shown below)

```
{
   posts:[{...}, {...}, {...}],
   authors:[
     {id:1, name:'Author-A'},
     {id:2, name:'Author-B'}
   ]
}
```

Comment: It is quite possible but then you would loose the relation..whats the point of doing it..it is as good as having two ActiveRecord objects individually.

Comment: There are several components in system which expects the data in the above mentioned format. 

This was possible in AMS 0.8.x using the embed :ids but couldn't find the equivalent for this in AMS 0.10.x

Comment: 0.8 can be thought of an early draft of jsonapi. Embed became included.

Comment: @BF4 I assume you are referring to the 'include:' in the option for associations. Please correct if otherwise.. This doesn't modify the json format. (when using json adapter)

Comment: @Pratheeswaran.R Well, there's an include query param and an included json root.  In any case, I wasn't referring to code when when I said embed became included.. I mean that JSON:API was in development for a while before it reached 1.0, and embed was the predecessor to include, and AMS was where a lot of early JSON:API was implemented. I apologize if I didn't address the right question. I intended to answer why embed is missing from 0.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, we created a custom adapter extending the Json adapter and modifying the hash to our desired format in the serializable_hash(...) method

```
class CustomAdapter < ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::Json
  def serializable_hash(options = nil)
    result_hash = super(options)
    ... code to modify hash format ...
    result_hash
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to mimic the jsonapi included relationships.  So, w json adapter, post has an attribute, to keep things simple, author_id, and then, you render the post collection separately from authors and generate the response, or you renders them mixed and reduce them. You may be able to just render as [posts, authors]!